# Convert Binary to Decimal in MASM32

Tags: assembly, binary, decimal, masm32

Convert decial to binary in MASM32. Help me

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.code

start:
  call main
  exit

main proc
  LOCAL var1: DWORD
  LOCAL dem: DWORD
    
  mov var1, sval(input("Enter Binary Number: "))
  mov dem, strlen(str$(var1))
  mov ecx, dem
  mov ebx, 1
  mov dec, 0
  
lbl0:
  DEC ecx
  cmp ecx, 0
  jl lbl1
  
  mov eax, var1
  and eax, ebx
  mov edx, eax
  shl edx, cl
  add dec, edx
  shl ebx, 1
  jmp lbl0
  
lbl1:
  print chr$(13,10)
  print chr$("Decimal Equivalent: ")
  print str$(dec)
  print chr$(13,10)
  
  ret
  main endp
  
end start
```

here r my code but it don't work

Comment: "Here's my code, it doesn't work" is not a great way to ask for help.  Tell us what you have tried, how you have troubleshot the problem, in what way the code does not perform as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The title askes for "Convert Binary to Decimal", but the text askes for "Convert decial to binary".
Your program attempts what's in the title...

---

> ```
> mov var1, sval(input("Enter Binary Number: "))
> ...
> print chr$("Decimal Equivalent: ")
> print str$(dec)
> ```

Since you are using these advanced functions anyway, why not just solve the task with a mere `str$(var1)`:

```
print chr$("Decimal Equivalent: ")
print str$(var1)
```

The 'conversion' loop that you show us isn't converting to decimal representation at all.

> ```
> mov dem, strlen(str$(var1))
> mov ecx, dem
> ```

`strlen` gives you the number of characters in a string, so then what is this particular loop count in ECX going to do?

---

See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) for how to convert your integer into a string of decimal characters.